# Is there any standart extjs method to find visible root of selected node?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an extjs Ext.tree.Panel. Main root of this tree is not visible. Child nodes of this root are all accessible. When I click on children of these visible roots I have to find visible root node of selected node. Is there any standart method to find visible root of node, or find element by level of tree, which is a parent of that node? Should I iterate all parent nodes of selected item and compare with defined list of visible roots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `getVisibleRoot` method on the [`NodeInterface`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface), indeed.

You have to come up with your own one.

For example, the following method added to `Ext.tree.Panel` will do the trick:

```
getVisibleRoot: function(node) {
    var p,
        isRootVisible = this.getStore().getRootVisible();
    while ((p = node.parentNode) && (!p.isRoot() || isRootVisible)) {
        node = p;
    };
    return node;        
},
```

See it in action: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/scg